# Suddenly getting connection timeout from my server

Tags: mailgun, mailgun-api

I have been using Mailgun for a while and it worked just fine.

Suddenly the connection stopped working, with a connection timeout to *api.mailgun.net*

I send a small amount of normal emails (around 4k emails a month). There isn't any notice in my Mailgun dashboard and it also works fine using the same setup from a different server.

I contacted the service providers at my current hosting and they say there is no block or firewall going on.

They also told me that they tried the *traceroute* command with no luck:

```
traceroute to api.mailgun.net (34.160.157.95), 100 hops max, 60 byte packets
send: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Sounds like their API has problems. If even a traceroute is not running properly, you can't do anything in PHP to circumvent this problem

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks. But... why would their API work from all other locations except from my domain? What can I do to double check this and potentially find out the reason? Thanks.

Comment: If your hosting provider can't run that traceroute properly, but you can from any other system, that might be a problem of your hosting provider